# Definition of a ROI publisher with c++

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi communitiy,
I'm currently using the procrob functional face detection package, which is completely written in c++. In one of the functions I am getting a rectangle that includes a recognized face. The variables that I get are: x- and y-postition of the upper left corner pixel and the width and height of the rectangle. I want to publish these information as a RegionOfInterest. But I don't know how to define the ROI-Publisher in c++. Does anyone else know?

Thank you for your help,
Greetings from Germany,
Bison

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61347/definition-of-a-roi-publisher-with-c++/) by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a pretty good [tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Publisher_Node) describing how to write topic publishers in C++.

Here is a small code sample that should get you started.  Note that you'll need to also set up a package, package.xml, and CMakeLists.txt as described [here](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/RegionOfInterest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "faceROI");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest>("faceROI", 1000);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while (ros::ok())
  {
    <do your code to calculate Face ROI here>

    sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest roi_msg;
    roi_msg.x_offset = 10;
    roi_msg.y_offset = 10;
    roi_msg.height = 200;
    roi_msg.width = 100;

    pub.publish(roi_msg);

    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bison](https://answers.ros.org/users/4239/bison/) on 2013-04-23**:
Thank you very much. That's exactly what i was looking for. I did the tutorial but I am really not into c++ yet. Greetings from Germany